# Create a unit test for a cookie creator static method

Tags: c#, webforms, nunit, moq, mvp

I have this static method in a static class:

```
public static class CookieHelper //:ICookieHelper
{
    public static void CreateCookie(string cookieName, int expireyDays)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie;
        cookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieName]; //Exception is here
        cookie.Expires.AddDays(expireyDays);
    }
}
```

I wrote this unit test for it. Running this test is generating a nullreferenceexception (object reference not set to ...).

```
[Test]
public void ShouldCreateCookieAndValidateNotNull()
{
    string newCookie = "testCookie";

    CookieHelper.CreateCookie(newCookie,5);

    string cookieValue = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request[newCookie]);

    Assert.NotNull(cookieValue);
}
```

This is always invoked in code behind of a webform; never in the presenter layer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't mention where the `NullReferenceException` occurs, but `HttpContext.Current` is likely to be null when your `CreateCookie` function is called outside of a HTTP call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are tightly coupling your implementation with HttpContext.Current, which is not a good idea.

I would suggest that you recreate your helper to accept [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) which it uses to create the cookie. Or even [HttpResponseBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponsebase.aspx), as it does not need the context at all.

Then, from your controller you can use the current controller context (or response) to pass into the helper.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set up `HttpContext.Current` as a new `HttpContext` with a new `HttpResponse` during your test initialization:

```
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
    new HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", "ip=127.0.0.1"),
    new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()))
    {
        User = new GenericPrincipal(
            new GenericIdentity("username"),
            new string[0]),
    };
```